# How to remove an account from an arraylist with the account number specified as a parameter

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm not sure how to correct this in order to make it work,

/** Should remove the Account with the account number specified as a parameter if it the Account exists. The appropriate boolean value should then be returned via a method result dialog box. */

```
public boolean removeAccount(String accountNumber)
{

    int index = 0;

    for(Account account : accounts)
    {
         if((account.getAccountNumber() == accountNumber) && index < accounts.size()) 
               accounts.remove(account);
         else
               index++;
    }

}
```

tried with an iterator

```
public boolean removeAccount(String accountNumber)
{
    Iterator<Account> i = accounts.iterator();
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        Account s = i.next(); // must be called before you can call i.remove()
        if(s.getAccountNumber().equals(accountNumber))
            return i.remove();
    }
    return false;
}
```

and I get "incompatible type: void cannot be converted to boolean"

Comment: You shouldn't use an enhanced for loop when you have to modify the collection; always use the iterator. Look at the return type of the `remove` method: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove()

Answer (score 1):

try

```
public boolean removeAccount(String accountNumber)
{
    Iterator<Account> i = accounts.iterator();
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        Account s = i.next(); // must be called before you can call i.remove()
        if(s.getAccountNumber().equals(accountNumber)){
            i.remove();
            return true; 
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Iterator.remove()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove()) returns nothing - it is declared as `void`.

Just use the `true` constant.

```
i.remove();
return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't delete from a list while iterating over it. Get a reference to it while iterating, and then remove it from the list AFTER the iteration.

```
public boolean removeAccount(String accountNumber)
{

int index = 0;
Account toRemove;
for(Account account : accounts)
{
     if (account.getNumber.equals(accountNumber)){
       toRemove=account;
     }
}
accounts.remove(toRemove)

}
```

obviously missing nullchecks etc.

Answer (score -2):

For your iterator try, you have NOT called the right remove method. As explained in the JavaDoc for an Iterator, remove() will return void. You may want to consider something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < accounts.size(); i++)
{
Account a = accounts.get(i);
if(a.getAccountNumber().equals(accountNumber))
{
return accounts.remove(i);
}
}
```